# Both button background color changed

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

When I'm using that function, the button not correctly worked. When I tapped on button then the button background color will change and when we tap on another button, then the background color of both the button will change. Please tell me how to solve this bug.

```
@IBAction func btnNew(_ sender: Any)
    {
        if otlNewVisitor.isSelected == false
        {
            otlNewVisitor.isSelected == true
            Button.buttonPressed(button: otlNewVisitor, boolResult: true, titleColor: UIColor.white, strImage: "icn-new-visitor-wht", bgColor: UIColor(red: 30/255, green: 104/255, blue: 140/255, alpha: 1), imgVW: imgNewVis)

            //Entered SubmitDetails Screen
            let submitVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SubmitDetailsVC") as! SubmitDetailsVC
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(submitVC, animated: true)
        }
        else
        {
            otlNewVisitor.isSelected == false
            //Button Colow did change
            Button.buttonPressed(button: otlNewVisitor, boolResult: false, titleColor: UIColor(red: 30/255, green: 104/255, blue: 140/255, alpha: 1), strImage: "icn-new-visitor", bgColor: UIColor.white, imgVW: imgNewVis)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show code for `Button.buttonPressed`

Comment: Also you are not setting state with `==` after the comparison (probably you are getting a warning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can changed your code to my code. This is only happens when you set the selected value of button within the if-else condition. So, you want to remove that code. It works well.

```
@IBAction func btnNew(_ sender: Any)
    {
        if otlNewVisitor.isSelected == false
        {
            Button.buttonPressed(button: otlNewVisitor, boolResult: true, titleColor: UIColor.white, strImage: "icn-new-visitor-wht", bgColor: UIColor(red: 30/255, green: 104/255, blue: 140/255, alpha: 1), imgVW: imgNewVis)

            //Entered SubmitDetails Screen
            let submitVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SubmitDetailsVC") as! SubmitDetailsVC
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(submitVC, animated: true)
        }
        else
        {
            //Button Colow did change
            Button.buttonPressed(button: otlNewVisitor, boolResult: false, titleColor: UIColor(red: 30/255, green: 104/255, blue: 140/255, alpha: 1), strImage: "icn-new-visitor", bgColor: UIColor.white, imgVW: imgNewVis)
        }
    }
```